# I am getting more prediction values in random forest than new data supplied to it?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying out to solve exercises of ISLR. During one exercise of Random Forest, when I am trying to predict values based on training data set. I am getting more prediction values than new data supplied.

- Total rows in data set = 506
- Rows used in training set = 300
- Rows used in test set = 206

I am using `predict()` function for obtaining predictions on new data set.

```
train = sample(1:nrow(Boston),300) 
rf.p = randomForest(medv~., data= Boston, subset= train, mtry = dim(Boston)[2]-1) 
pred.p = predict(rf.p, newdata = Boston[-train,])
```

I was expecting length of `pred.p`as to be 206 as
the length of `Boston[-train,]` but i am getting `pred.p` as vector of
length 503.

Comment: how many unique IDs are you seeing?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see how to create a [MCVE], which should be straightforward with a public data set like Boston - the row numbers you have posted do not add up...

Comment: It seems you do not have testing set as according to your description, you separated your set into two training sets: `Rows used in training set = 303` and
`Rows used in training set = 203`. Of course, if it's not a typo here...

Comment: Oh, sorry there was a typo here. Very silly of me.